# How to close ComboBox list items when moving application window of my WinRT/C++ UWP application?

Tags: xaml, uwp, mfc, winrt-xaml, c++-winrt

I have a pair of ComboBox controls having IsEditable() true as well as false.

When I am scrolling through my application or moving my application window (by clicking on the title bar) with list popup open, I would like to close the ComboBox list popup as otherwise there would be a weird delay in aligning the list correctly below the control.

Is this possible in UWP with WinRT/C++? If so, kindly suggest how to.

I did an investigation to find if any events are there to handle in such a scenario when ComboBox control is essentially displaced from initial position while moving the app window/scrolling the app, but couldn't find any help.

Edit: Adding ComboBox image from XAML Controls Gallery to demonstrate the behaviour. In case if IsEditable set as true, when popup is opened and application is scrolled then popup goes outside the window. Instead I would like to dismiss the popup itself. However, if IsEditable is set as false then we cannot scroll until the popup is dismissed.

[image]

Update: The code I tested for PointerWheelChanged

```
void CBFile2022X::OnPointerWheelChangedHandler( Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender,
                                               Windows::UI::Xaml::Input::PointerRoutedEventArgs const& eventargs )
    {
         OutputDebugString( L"PointerWheelChanged" );

         if( ComboBox != nullptr )
         {
             ComboBox.IsEnabled( false );
             ComboBox.IsEnabled( true );
         }
    }
```

Comment: *"moving my application window with list popup open"* - How do you get into this situation to begin with? If a popup is active, then all keyboard input goes to the popup, so you cannot move the window with the keyboard. If you attempt to move the window with the mouse then that activates the main window, causing any open popup to get closed.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for the response! The scenario I mentioned is when the application window is not maximized/full screen, that is in "Restore down" mode. At that time we can move the application window by mouse clicking the title bar at the top. While doing this, popup is not closed but remains open and moves along with the combobox with a slight delay. We wanted to handle this movement scenario, along with application scroll scenario (here if the window is not full screen then the popup alone will be displayed outside app window when we scroll within the app, so we wish to close it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to say that currently there is no event to detect if the application window is moved or changed its location.

Update:

You could handle the [UIElement.PointerWheelChanged Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.pointerwheelchanged?view=winrt-22000) which will be fired when users scroll the mouse wheel. You could set the `IsEnabled` property of the ComboBox to **false** first and then set it to **true**, this will make the ComboBox lose its focus. Like:

```
   private void Mypanel_PointerWheelChanged(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FontsCombo.IsEnabled = false;
        FontsCombo.IsEnabled = true;
    }
```

**Update2:**

If you are using a `ScrollViewer` you could try to handle the [ScrollViewer.ViewChanging Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.viewchanging?view=winrt-22000).

```
  private void ScrollViewer_ViewChanging(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        FontsCombo.IsEnabled = false;
        FontsCombo.IsEnabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: I'd suggest you submit a feature request about this feature in the Feedback Hub. You could find the Feedback Hub in the Start Menu. Please select **Developer Platform**->**API Feedback** as the category when you submit your request. The related team will check the request.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However, is it possible to know when the scroll happens? In my case I verified all the available events for ComboBox to check but none were fired when the application is scrolled. We wanted to check if the popup could be closed in such a case.

Comment: @LeJackArcher I'm not sure what the scroll that you mean. Do you mean the popup of the ComboBox?

Comment: Not inside the popup. For example I have around 10 combo box and corresponding labels in an application window and a vertical scroll bar is visible. In this application, when I open the first combo box popup and then scroll vertically down in the application (not inside the popup) towards 10th combo box , I want to close the first combo box popup. Otherwise we can see the popup going outside the application window towards the top (when application is not in full screen). Actually the same behaviour is seen in XAML Controls Gallery as well.

Comment: @LeJackArcher I'm confused about the behavior that you described. To be more specific about the scenario you mentioned. could you please update your question with a screenshot of the behavior?

Comment: I have attached a screenshot from the XAML Controls Gallery application to demonstrate the behaviour.  As we can see in the image, in case of IsEditable true, when the popup is opened and we scroll the application, the popup moves outside of the application window. This is the current behaviour. However, I wish to handle such a scenario so as to dismiss the popup, instead of showing it overflow out of the app window.

Comment: @LeJackArcher What's the device that you are testing? Is that a tablet?

Comment: No, I am testing in a Windows 10 desktop. Application window has been resized to show the popup overflow.

Comment: @LeJackArcher I've updated my answer, please check that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, when I tried the PointerWheelChanged event itself is not being fired while testing. Updated the question with the code I tried. Also, this might be workaround only for mouse wheel scroll, but when we scroll using the scroll bar still the behaviour will not change right..

Comment: @LeJackArcher I've updated my asnwer.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Really appreciate your patience in helping me out!